# Приём файлов AJAX -> PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Не могу разобраться, при отправке файлов без `Ajax` - всё норм, при отправке через `Ajax` - письмо с вложением не отправляется.

```
$to = 'sergeykozin1@yandex.ru';
if ( isset( $_POST['sendMail'] ) ) {

$post = array(
  'name'   => 'Имя: ', // и т.д. 
);

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $body .= ( $post[$key] ? $post[$key] : ($key . ': ') ) . $value . PHP_EOL;
}

if($_FILES)
{
  $filepath = array();
  $filename = array();
  $file2 = array();
  $i = 0;
    foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
      if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $filename[$i][0] = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $filename[$i][1] = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key];
        $i++;
      }
    }
  }

  $body .= "Файл:\r\n".$file."\r\n\r\n";
  send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filename);
}



// Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением
function send_mail($to, $body, $email, $filename)
{
  $subject = 'Заказ с сайта ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
  $boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель
  $headers = "From: ". 'vsedlyastudentov.ru' ."\r\n";   
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\r\n";
  $multipart = "--".$boundary."\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
  $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n";

  $body = $body."\r\n\r\n";

  $multipart .= $body;
  foreach ($filename as $key => $value) {
    $fp = fopen($value[0], "r"); 
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($value[0]));
    fclose($fp);
    $file .= "--".$boundary."\r\n";
    $file .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
    $file .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $file .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$value[1]."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $file .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content))."\r\n";
  }
  $multipart .= $file."--".$boundary."--\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers);

}
```

```js
$("#file_form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var $input = $("#file");
  var fd = new FormData;

  fd.append('img', $input.prop('files')[0]);
  $.ajax({
      url: 'file.php',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: 'POST',
    })
    .done(function(html) {
      //безполезный код
    })
})
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file_form">

  <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file">

  <input type="submit" value="Узнать стоимость" name="sendMail">
</form>
```

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Заранее большое спасибо)

Comment: Вы отправляете письмо если только в POST пришло sendMail. В JS коде я пока не вижу чтобы вы как-то отправляли через Ajax эту переменную/значение. В PHP скрипт она вообще приходит?

Comment: sendMail Это name у кнопки submit. Т.е. проверка, если нажали на кнопку...

Comment: Да, вы правы, через ajax она не передается и походу ничего не передаётся оО, при услувии if (true) {///} на почту приходит пустое письмо хотя форма заполнена....

Comment: Когда вы просто отправляете форму то переменная с именем sendMail передаётся через POST. (Т.к передаются все данные где есть name). При отправке через Ajax все эти данные необходимо отдавать вручную.

Comment: кошмар...спасибо за мысль, сейчас погуглю)

Comment: просто если отправлять `data: $(this).serialize()` то собираются все данные кроме вложений...засада

Comment: попробуйте добавить fd.append('sendMail', 'sendMail');

Answer (score 1):

Вобщем нагуглил рабочий ответ [здесь](https://codeby.net/forma-obratnoj-svjazi-s-ispolzovaniem-ajax-otpravkoj-soobshhenija-po-pochte-i-vozmozhnostju-prikrepit-fajl/)

```js
// этот участок кода нужен только для отображения гифки
// которая даёт пользователю понять, что что-то происходит
// и нужно подождать
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    // найдем элемент с изображением загрузки и уберем невидимость:
    var imgObj = $("#load-indicator");
    imgObj.show();
    // вычислим в какие координаты нужно поместить изображение загрузки,
    // чтобы оно оказалось в серидине страницы:
    var centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() + imgObj.height()) / 2;
    var centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() + imgObj.width()) / 2;
    imgObj.offset({
      left: centerX,
      top: centerY
    });
  });
  //скрываем изображение после окончания AJAX-запроса
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#load-indicator').hide();
  });
});

// назначаем действие на такое событие как отправка формы
$('#feedback').submit(function(evtObj) {
  evtObj.preventDefault();
  // Если элемент формы fileforsending содержит значения (т.е. выбран файл для отправки),
  // то вместо AJAX-запроса используем FormData()
  // поскольку файлы через AJAX-запросы не передаются                

  if (document.getElementById("feedback").fileforsending.value !== '') {
    //показываем гифку ожидания
    var imgObj = $("#load-indicator");
    imgObj.show();
    var centerY = $(window).scrollTop() + ($(window).height() + imgObj.height()) / 2;
    var centerX = $(window).scrollLeft() + ($(window).width() + imgObj.width()) / 2;
    imgObj.offset({
      left: centerX,
      top: centerY
    });
    // этот кусок кода я спёр отсюда http://javascript.ru/forum/jquery/40698-ajax-i-otpravka-fajjlov-s-formy.html
    var form = document.forms.feedback;
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "mails_sender.php");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
          data = xhr.responseText;
          $("#result").html('Результат выполнения: ' + data);
          // Письмо отправлено, сбрасываем данные формы если прошло успешно
          if (data === 'Отправлено письмо с вложениями.') {
            document.getElementById("feedback").reset();
          }
          //убираем гифку ожидания
          $('#load-indicator').hide();
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.send(formData);
    // В противном случае (не прикреплён файл для отправки)
    // Делаем AJAX-запрос для отправки письма
  } else {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      // Здесь файл, который обрабатывает полученные от пользователя данные и отправляет почту
      url: 'mails_sender.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: form.serialize(),
      // Действия в случае успешной отправки AJAX-запроса (а не письма!)
      // Здесь data - полученное от mails_sender.php сообщение
      success: function(data) {
        if (data === 'Отправлено письмо без вложений.') {
          $("#result").html('Отправлено письмо без вложений.');
          // Письмо отправлено, сбрасываем данные формы
          document.getElementById("feedback").reset();
          // Следующая строка после успешной отправки сообщения
          // перенаправляет пользователь на любую страницу/сайт
          // достаточно раскомментировать её и поменять адрес сайта codeby.net
          // на ваш собственный
          //document.location.href = 'https://codeby.net';
        } else {
          $("#result").html(data);
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {
        $("#result").html('Результат выполнения: ' + data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="mails_sender.php" id="feedback" name="feedback" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">Ваш e-mail</td>
      <td><input name="youremail" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">Тема сообщения</td>
      <td><input name="subject" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Опции для выбора:</td>
      <td>
        <select name="option" style="width: 440px">
                            <option style='color:#CCCCCC;'>- - Выберите из списка - -</option>
                            <option value="Опция 1">Опция 1</option>
                            <option value="Опция 1">Опция 2</option>
                            <option value="Опция 1">Опция 3</option>
                        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">Ваше сообщение</td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="message" style="width: 440px; height: 130px" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">Ваше имя</td>
      <td><input name="name" type="text" style="width: 440px" size="20" value="" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">Вы можете присоединить необходимые файлы</td>
      <td><input name="fileforsending" type="file" style="width: 440px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 146px">&nbsp;</td>
      <td><br />
        <input name="Reset1" type="reset" value="Очистить" style="width: 97px" />
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                            <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Отправить" style="width: 157px" />
                            &nbsp; </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<div style="color: red;" id="result"></div><br />
<img src="ajax-loader.gif" id="load-indicator" alt="loading" style="position:absolute; z-index:1000; display:none;" />
```

```html
<?php
 
// Адрес, куда отправляем письмо
$to = 'mial@localhost';
 
// Получаем данные от пользователя
// Все данные обязательно нужно проверять на правильность!
$userEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'youremail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$option = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$message = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES), '<p><a><b><div>');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
 
// Проверка, что данные не пустые. 
// Нас не интересуют анонимки
if (empty($userEmail)) {
    die('Отсутствует или неверен адрес почты.');
// Нас не интересуют послания с пустым сообщением
} elseif (empty($message)) {
    die('Отсутствует сообщение.');
} elseif (empty($subject)) {
    $subject = '[тема не указана]';
}
 
$the_file = '';
//Если пользователь выбрал файл для отправки
if (!empty($_FILES['fileforsending']['tmp_name'])) {
    // Закачиваем файл
    $path = $_FILES['fileforsending']['name'];
    if (copy($_FILES['fileforsending']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
        $the_file = $path;
    }
}
// Если есть прикреплённый файл, то заголовки чуть другие.
// Поэтому, в зависимости от того, отправил ли пользователь файл,
// выбираем, что делать дальше
$headers = null;
 
if (empty($the_file)) {
    // эта часть кода отвечает за отправку сообщений без вложений
    // собираем заголовки
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    $headers[] = "From: $name <$userEmail>";
    $headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    // собираем текст письма
    $allmsg = "<p><b>E-mail:</b> $userEmail</p>
        <p><b>Выбранная опция:</b> $option</p>
            <p><b>Сообщение:</b> $message</p>";
    $allmsg = "<html><head><title>Обратная связь</title><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>" . $allmsg . "</body></html>";
    // отправляем
    if (!mail($to, $subject, $allmsg, implode("rn", $headers))) {
        echo 'Письмо не отправлено - что-то не сработало.';
    } else {
        echo 'Отправлено письмо без вложений.';
    }
} else {
    // эта часть кода отвечает за отправку сообщений с вложениями
    // читаем отправляемый файл в строку
    $fp = fopen($the_file, "r");
    if (!$the_file) {
        die("Ошибка отправка письма: Файл $the_file не может быть прочитан.");
    }
    $file = fread($fp, filesize($path));
    fclose($fp);
    // удаляем временный файл
    unlink($path);
    // собираем текст письма
    $allmsg = "<p><b>E-mail:</b> $userEmail</p>
        <p><b>Выбранная опция:</b> $option</p>
            <p><b>Сообщение:</b> $message</p>";
    $allmsg = "<html><head><title>Обратная связь</title><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>" . $allmsg . "</body></html>";
    // генерируем разделитель
    $boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time()));
    // собираем заголовки
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "From: $name <$userEmail>";
    $headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
    $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="$boundary"n";
    // собираем текст письма + приложенынй файл
    $multipart = array();
    $multipart[] = "--$boundary";
    $multipart[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    $multipart[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printedrn";
    $multipart[] = "$allmsgrn";
    $multipart[] = "--$boundary";
    $multipart[] = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream";
    $multipart[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
    $multipart[] = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = "" . $path . ""rn";
    $multipart[] = chunk_split(base64_encode($file));
    $multipart[] = "--$boundary";
    // отправляем
    if (!mail($to, $subject, implode("rn", $multipart), implode("rn", $headers))) {
        echo 'Письмо не отправлено - что-то не сработало.';
    } else {
        echo 'Отправлено письмо с вложениями.';
    }
}

$userEmail = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'youremail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$subject = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'subject', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$option = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'option', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
$message = strip_tags(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'message', FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES), '<p><a><b><div>');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
```